# Listen for exit of process given pid $$

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, proc

Say I have a pid in hand, `mypid=$$`

is there some bash/system command I can use to listen for the exit of that process with the given pid?

If no process with mypid exists, I guess the command should simply fail.

Comment: I don't use C#, but apparently there must be a way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In Unix, it's common to wait for _child processes_ using `wait` in the shell or the `wait()` C library function. There is AFAIK no standard way of waiting for a non-child process.  It is further unclear if the C# function can do that (it depends on what an "associated process" is).

Comment: I could do this with polling but that would be awful

Comment: It would also potentially give you the wrong results.  PID reuse may theoretically mean that a process could come alive with the same PID as the process you are waiting for. On Linux (with sequential PIDs) this would be _unlikely_, but on systems like OpenBSD (randomized PID allocation), it would be an issue.

Answer (score 55):

I got what I needed from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613532/1223975

..turns out using `wait <pid>` *will only work if that pid is a child process of the current process*.

However the following will work for any process:

#### To wait for any process to finish

Linux:

```
tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
```

Darwin (requires that `$pid` has open files):

```
lsof -p $pid +r 1 &>/dev/null
```

#### With timeout (seconds)

Linux:

```
timeout $timeout tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
```

Darwin (requires that `$pid` has open files):

```
lsof -p $pid +r 1m%s -t | grep -qm1 $(date -v+${timeout}S +%s 2>/dev/null || echo INF)
```

Comment: It's not related to Linux, it's a feature of GNU tail. So it will work on any system with GNU tail like GNU/Linux ones, and it wouldn't work on non-GNU Linux-based systems.

Comment: I fear that tail/lsof will use polling in this case, at least given the empirical evidence it appears that way on MacOS.

Comment: lsof +r puts it in repeat mode, so that command is repeating every second so it's using polling, damn

Comment: gnu ``tail`` is available to install via homebrew on macOS (Darwin), and becomes available as ``gtail``. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332. Is ``tail --pid`` preferable over ``lsof -p``?

Comment: @AlexanderMills strace shows the same on Linux: it's polling once a second

Comment: It’s messed-up that `pidwait` doesn’t do this, and `wait` doesn’t let one give a pid too.

Comment: it is messed up

Comment: I think `inotify` can make this more evented to avoid polling, but it's been awhile

Comment: AWESOME!!! I was still resorting to the sleep loop, but this is precise, simple and, apparently, portable.

Answer (score 5):

The portable way is to poll using kill, i.e. something like:

```
until kill -s 0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

This doesn't require non-portable commands such as GNU tail or lsof, and, in bash, only invokes one external command, namely sleep. GNU tail is likely a bit more efficient, since it was written in C (and could, in theory, take advantage of advanced functions such as `pidfd_open`), and lsof is likely going to have a lot of overhead.

A rough timeout can be implemented by counting the number of loop iterations.

A slightly less portable solution that only works for one waiter is to use ptrace(2), which doesn't have a portable shell interface, but which can be accessed using the strace command on some systems:

```
strace -e exit -e signal=none -p "$pid"
```

Comment: See also `until` as an equivalent (and slightly more portable as `!` is not Bourne) of `while !`. And `kill -s 0` as the POSIX equivalent of POSIX+XSI `kill -0`.

Comment: GNU tail is available as ``gtail`` after you install coreutils via homebrew (works even on M1 Mac): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332. Are we sure if tail is much more efficient for the job compared to lsof? am not a unix/linux expert.

Comment: `strace -p <PID>` works for me. It even shows `wait()` with child process exit status.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bash builtin `wait`:

```
$ sleep 10 &
[2] 28751
$ wait 28751
[2]-  Done                    sleep 10
$ help wait
wait: wait [-n] [id ...]
    Wait for job completion and return exit status.

    Waits for each process identified by an ID, which may be a process ID or a
    job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
    given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
    status is zero.  If ID is a a job specification, waits for all processes
    in that job's pipeline.

    If the -n option is supplied, waits for the next job to terminate and
    returns its exit status.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid
    option is given.
```

It uses the system call `waitpid()` ..

```
$ whatis waitpid
waitpid (2)          - wait for process to change state
```

Comment: nice that works for me, hopefully doesn't use polling under the hood, thanks!

Comment: yeah won't work for my use case, I get this error: `bash: wait: pid 47760 is not a child of this shell`...back to the drawing board lol

Comment: I have answer, I just posted it thx

Comment: This will only wait for child processes, not for a process unassociated with the current process.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613532/1223975 solution that Alexander Mills reposted, `Timeout in Seconds` `Darwin`, is a workaround for a UNIX-like OS that does not have GNU `tail`.  It is not specific to `Darwin`, but, depending on the age of the UNIX-like operating system, the command-line offered is more complex than necessary, and can fail:

```
lsof -p $pid +r 1m%s -t | grep -qm1 $(date -v+${timeout}S +%s 2>/dev/null || echo INF)
```

On at least one old UNIX, the `lsof` argument `+r 1m%s` fails (even for a superuser):

```
lsof: can't read kernel name list.
```

The `m%s` is an output format specification.  A simpler post-processor does not require it.  For example, the following command waits on PID 5959 for up to five seconds:

```
lsof -p 5959 +r 1 | awk '/^=/ { if (T++ >= 5) { exit 1 } }'
```

In this example, if PID 5959 exits of its own accord before the five seconds elapses, `${?}` is `0`.  If not `${?}` returns `1` after five seconds.

It may also be worth expressly noting that in `+r 1`, the `1` is the poll interval (in seconds), so it may be changed to suit the situation.

Comment: GNU tail is available as ``gtail`` after you install coreutils via homebrew (works even on M1 Mac): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332. The answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626632/456507 suggests that GNU tail will be more efficient compared to lsof for the job, though idk.

Comment: "a UNIX-like OS that does not have GNU tail" is not necessarily an Apple OS that has ready access to GNU tail built for it.  This answer was written expressly for a situation where GNU tail was not available or a user didn't want to have to get it.  A careful read of the answer shows that the goal of the answer was to supply a solution that had greater cross-platform compatibility.